# Can you change HDMI color spaces using the amdgpu driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, hdmi, amd-graphics

I'm using Kubuntu 17.04 with a television set over HDMI. As far as I can tell, this TV doesn't handle 'full' RGB properly. On consoles and Windows, I would set the appropriate option - with AMD on Windows, it was switching to the YCbCr color format (otherwise known as the YUV color space). This doesn't appear to happen using the standard amdgpu open source driver, and blacks are heavily crushed. I don't believe I have any way to make my TV recognize full-range RGB.

When I used AMDGPU-PRO, despite many problems, it did seem to properly detect that I was using a television set without intervention. But I can't use the closed source driver with 17.04, due to kernel issues and not really feeling confident about downgrading my kernel or other hacks to make it work, so I want to know if there's some option I've missed somewhere.

Both Intel and Nvidia cards have the option to change to a limited RGB or YUV format, on one driver or another. I'm not sure why AMD would be different, but if there's some way to do this, I'd love to know so I can stop fussing over it constantly.

I'm using an R9 285, if it matters.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/8bwul6/how_to_switch_the_pixel_format_for_amdgpu_on_linux/